# Upgrading EKS node group from 1.17 to 1.18 failed due to AsgInstanceLaunchFailures - how do I fix it?

Tags: upgrade, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster that has gone through an upgrade from 1.17 to 1.18.
The cluster has 2 node groups (updated using the AWS console).

EKS control plane and one of the node groups upgrades were ok.

The last node group the upgrade is failing due to a health issue - `AsgInstanceLaunchFailures - One or more target groups not found. Validating load balancer configuration failed.` and now the node group is marked as `Degraded`.

when I access the update ID I see the following error:

```
NodeCreationFailure - Couldn't proceed with upgrade process as new nodes are not joining node group {NODE_GROUP_NAME}
```

I tried accessing the ASG with that ID and I can see it has several load-balancing target groups attached to it.
I could not find any way to fix this in the AWS docs.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved.

it appears there was an empty target group added manually to the cluster (there were 3 other target groups created automatically). Once the empty target group was deleted, the upgrade was completed successfully.

I am still unclear as to how EKS chooses the proper target group to update when there is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to launch new nodes which are coming up in Ready State and joining cluster? Based on [EKS public doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-update-behavior.html), the upgrade request would succeed only when ASG can launch new instances in Ready state in all the AZs of the node group.

To debug this further, you can trigger a new upgrade request and check the health of new nodes which EKS brings up in your cluster.

Comment: As you can see from my previous comment - the issue was resolved by removing an empty target group from the asg - leaving it with usable target groups that are able to launch new instances